# How to set my VPN connection as Non-metered in Windows 10?

Tags: networking, windows-10, vpn, connection

I want to explicitly tell Windows 10 1909 to consider my VPN connection as non-metered.

whenever I connect to my VPN server, created from the Windows settings, apps like Mail stop showing me notifications, Store won't automatically update apps and things like that. Windows by default thinks my VPN connection is set as metered.

I went to

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\NetworkList\DefaultMediaCost
```

but there is no mention of my VPN connection's name

[image]

I manually set them all to "1" which means Non-metered.
that didn't help.

can anyone help me set my VPN connection as Non-metered so Windows 10 can use Internet as much as it wants just like when I connect to Internet without VPN? Thanks

**More info on this:**

**this is how advanced settings for WiFi looks like in Windows settings**

[image]

**And this is how advanced settings for VPN looks like in Windows settings**

[image]

You see the part about "Metered Connection" is missing from VPN settings!

Comment: What VPN software do you use?

Comment: Nothing. I use `PPTP/SSTP` protocols, you can set them up in `Windows 10 settings => Network & Internet => VPN` without any software.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in command prompt!
 Show profiles: `netsh wlan show profiles`
Set unmetered: `netsh wlan set profileparameter name="profile_name" cost=Unrestricted`

Comment: But my VPN is not a wlan and running the first command won't list my VPN name. it just shows my WIFI name which is already set as non-metered in the Windows 10 settings.